# Listen to a mouse event on condition

Tags: javascript, html, mouseevent, addeventlistener

I want to "listen to" a mouse event only if a checkbox is clicked. Therefore I have the following code:

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="magicLens" onchange="magicLens()">
<label for="magicLens">Magic Lens</label>
```

**JS**

```
function magicLens(){
  const magicLens_checked = document.getElementById('magicLens').checked;

  if (magicLens_checked === true){
      canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
         myAnonymous = arguments.callee;
         ...
         // draw something at the current mouse position
         // and therefore use the 'e' event object
    });
  }
  else {
      canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', myAnonymous);
  }
}
```

Problem is, that the drawing (a lens) also occurs when the checkbox is not checked (`false`). I'm not even sure if `removeEventListener()` is the right way to deal with it (though I already tried the whole thing without it and result was the same).

Maybe you have a better idea to describe the issue in the title. Feel free to edit!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee

Comment: what about adding mousemove listener on start and inside it check if magicLens is checked and decide to draw or not?

Comment: Using `arguments.callee` is bad practice so try using a named function instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easier to actually always listen to the event and in there check whether the checkbox is checked.

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
    const magicLens_checked = document.getElementById('magicLens').checked;

    if (!magicLens_checked) {
        return;
    }

    // Do something with e
    console.log(e);
});
```

You can check it out in this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/umws6y85/1/). (I added the event listener to document, to avoid creating an arbitrary canvas, but it works the same way)

Comment: That will work. Thanks! Isn't that a little "performance critical" as it always creates a new variable and checks an if-condition when the cursor moves (even when I don't need it)?

Comment: Hardly. (I hope I don't say anything wrong, but...) In javascript we don't assign variables to memory, instead they are references to objects. These are instantiated with the `new` keyword. Regarding the if-condition checking, I created a little jsperf snippet to show you it hardly makes a difference: https://jsperf.com/if-case-in-mouseevent

Comment: Alright, thank you again! Definitely the easier way than `removeEventListener()`...

Answer (score 0):

The Javascript engine sees what you pass to addEventListener and removeEventListener as two different functions which is why the removeEventListener is not working.  Create a named function outside of these and pass it into them.